# iOs6 - Take photo from Safari and save to photo album

Tags: php, html, ipad, ios6, safari

I'm developing a website with html/php. I have a button to upload photos. It works with typical html tags 'input type=file'. All works fine.

My problem is when the functionality is accessed from Safari in iphone/ipad (working in iOs6). When I select 'Take photo or video' works fine and the image is load to website but not is saved to device's camera roll.

I want save the image taken with safari to photo library.
How I can do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried in the way of debugging? Have you tried dumping `$_FILES` for instance? Do you receive any error messages?

Comment: I need to find a option in iOs6/Safari to config 'Take photo or video' to save photos to camera roll.
Otherwise, if it is not possible I need the html/php code for download the image from $_FILES structure to my iOs device camera roll.